# Closing the app after a set number of attempts

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on a login program and want to close the app after 3 failed attempts. The passwords do come up as wrong but I think there is an issue with the counter. Here is all of my code so far:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmMainScreen
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim ConnString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "H:\Visual studio files\Project\CMPC\uDat.accdb"
        ConnString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
        myConnection.Open()

        Dim userFound As Boolean = False
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM uDat WHERE [username] = '" & txtUsername.Text & "'AND [password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'", myConnection)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Dim username As String = ""
        Dim password As String = ""
        Dim attempts As Integer = 0
        While dr.Read
            userFound = True
            username = dr("Username").ToString
            password = dr("Password").ToString
        End While

        If userFound = True Then
            MsgBox("Welcome " + username, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            frmFilters3.Visible = False
            Me.Hide()
            frmFilters3.ShowDialog()
            myConnection.Close()
        ElseIf attempts = 3 Then
            MsgBox("You have reached the maximum tries. Please restart the app.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else
            attempts = attempts + 1
            Me.Refresh()
            If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                myConnection.Close()
            End If
            MsgBox("Username and password combination not found. 
Please try again or click register.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

    End If
End Sub`
```

Comment: First, change the logic. You need to check for 3 failed attempts AFTER you increment **attempts**.  If they have less than 3, they get one msgbox, but if they have 3, then they get a different msgbox and then close.  Second, closing the app is as simple as `Me.Close()`.  Have a go at that and post your updates.

Comment: Injection heaven here, use parameters. Also, please `Dispose` of objects when done using them.

Comment: You need to debug your code. You don't have to just think there's an issue with the counter. You can find out for sure and what it actually is. Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and then step through it line by line, testing the state at each step. You can then see exactly where and how the actual behaviour of the code differs from your expectations. Even if you still can't work out how to solve the problem, at least you can explain to us what the actual problem is. You should not be posting a question here without having debugged first. If you don't know how, learn now.

Comment: first of all your **attempt counter should be declare outside of button click event**  where your connection string is declare . In your current code whenever you click on button attempt counter reset to 0 and it gives you always 1 attempt ..

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the connection string as a whole at the form level.
Do not declare and instantiate a connection at Form level. Connections need to be disposed as soon as possible after use. There goes your connection. Using blocks handle database objects that requires disposal.

A Boolean is a value type with a default value of False. I changed the datatype of userFound to an Integer.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Don't open the connection until directly before the .Execute...
Don't pass data down from the server if all you need is the count.

**Always** use Parameters to avoid sql injection and other reasons. I had to guess at the datatypes of your fields. Check your database for the actual types and adjust the code.

Since we are only returning a single piece of data we can use .ExecureScalar which returns an Object. We must change the Object to an Integer.

We close the connection before checking the results and before showing any message boxes.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Visual studio files\Project\CMPC\uDat.accdb"    
Private NumberOfTries As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If NumberOfTries > 3 Then
        MsgBox("You have reached the maximum tries. Please restart the app.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Application.Exit()
    End If
    Dim userFound As Integer
    Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM uDat WHERE [username] = @Name AND [password] = @Password;", myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
        myConnection.Open()
        userFound = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using 'Disposes the command and closes and disposes the connection
    If userFound = 1 Then
        MsgBox($"Welcome {txtUserName.Text}", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        frmFilters3.Visible = False 'Not sure what this is about
        Me.Hide()
        frmFilters3.ShowDialog()
    Else
        NumberOfTries += 1
        MsgBox("Username and password combination not found. 
Please try again or click register.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If
End Sub
```